# How do you exclude the Hot Reload asset from Unity game builds

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently started using the Hot Reload asset for Unity. I would like to continue using it in the Unity editor, but I don't need to include it in game builds. I've tried opening the Hot Reload window, but it only shows a button for starting Hot Reload, not any settings. So I looked under Project Settings -> Player, but I can't seem to find anything about Hot Reload there. I know that it's being included in my game builds, because I saw it imported during the build, and I know that the asset supports use on device, not just in the editor, but I would prefer to simply leave it out of my builds if possible.

Comment: I understand your issue, Please share detail info for Hot Reload Package.

Comment: Hot Reload website: https://hotreload.net/documentation . I've looked through the documentation, but for some reason I just can't figure out how to specifically exclude it from builds. I clicked the "Fix all" button initially, which I think allowed it to be included in builds to begin with.

Comment: well you could use asmdefs and only have it in editor

Comment: I sent the developers an email, I'll post here if they get back to me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I couldn't open the settings menu in the Hot Reload window because the window wasn't expanded enough. See these screenshots:

Before expanding (the menu icon at the bottom only showed Suggestions and Timeline):
[image: before expanding]

After expanding:
[image: after expanding]

Comment: should open a bug report ;)